# strtok(): convert string to char*

Tags: c++, string, tokenize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c)

```
char *strtok(char *s1, const char *s2)
```

How can I convert a `string` to a char* as required by `strtok`? I did

```
for (string line; getline(sourceFile, line);) {
    tokens = strtok(line.c_str(), " {};");
}
```

Where `sourceFile` is an `ifstream` (`sourceFile.open(filepath.c_str());`)

I am getting:

> argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

Comment: Since it's C++, how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c

Comment: You don't want to use `strtok()` on a C++ string; `strtok()` mangles the string, inserting NUL `'\0'` at token ends.  Use something — anything — else.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you probably want to use something other than `strtok`.

However, to do what you are asking (and you probably shouldn't):

```
for (string line; getline(sourceFile, line);) {
    char* line_cstr = strdup(line.c_str());

    char* token = strtok(line_cstr, " {};");

    while ((token = strtok(NULL, " {};")) != NULL) {
        //code
    }

    free(line_cstr);

}
```

Comment: That is going to work well at the expense of duplicating the string, but I would recommend simply using boost::tokenizer instead.

Comment: @TimoGeusch I completely agree. No need to use these messy C functions when better alternatives are available.

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like this:

```
char fp[40];  // or some reasonable size
strcpy( fp, filepath.c_str()); // fp is not a const char* like c_str() returns
```

You should be able to use `strtok()` against `fp`.

But you might want to consider a more `C++` way of splitting strings.

Comment: Even then, making `fp` a `std::vector<char>(filepath.size())` would be better.

Comment: @chris: `std::vector<char>(filepath.size())` - it should be `size() + 1`, because you'll need it NUL terminated for `strtok()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan Leffler's comment explains, strtok actually modifies the buffer in place to terminate successive tokens.  That's great for speed - saves copying each token out to some other memory area while still giving you convenient access to it as a separate NUL-terminated sequence.  It's an interesting question whether it's legitimate to use strtok on a `std::string` instance - certainly, the `c_str()` member returns a `const char*` because you're not meant to write over parts of that buffer.  But, as long as you don't have an empty string (for which it'd give undefined behaviour), you can get a `char*` to the first element with `&line[0]`.  Having done that, you can mutate the string, but only at offsets `[0]..[size()-1]`... it's not guaranteed to be NUL terminated the way the `c_str()`-returned buffer is, and precisely because of that the `&line[0]`-returned buffer may not be suitable for use by `strtok`.  You could append a NUL (i.e. `line += '\0'` - NUL is legal `std::string` content), but it would make the code a bit hackish and harder to maintain, and you might need to remove the NUL afterwards if you're planning to use the original value for anything.

If you really want to use `strtok`, seems best to copy the data to a separate writable NUL-terminated buffer first.  For example:

```
char* p = strdup(line.c_str());
... use strtok on p ...
free(p);
```

You could use `alloca()`, a smart pointer, a `std::vector<char>` to minimise potential for memory leaks.  (I don't see any particular reason to prefer C++ `new` and `delete` for the above - you're using `strtok` anyway, but if you've smart-pointer libraries that expect it go for it).

All that said, finding another mechanism - like those in boost - is a better option.  I'm guessing alternatives like that are discussed in the link chris posted in a comment under your question....